# What is the use of 'self.update' in Roger Stuckey's wxPython Multiprocessing Example code

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I was reading Roger Stuckey's wxPython Multiprocessing code to try to make a similar program myself. Full code can be found [here](http://rogerstuckey.com/code/python/wxsimple_mp/).

The code runs fine without any modification. However, I found a parameter *self.update* been pass around between the GUI class **MyFrame** to the processing class **TaskSErverMP**. I have been searched throughout the entire code snippet and couldn't figure out what it is doing in the code -- it has never been initialized and used anyhow.

In the class MyFrame:

```
def OnStart(self, event):
   ...
   self.taskserver.processTasks(self.update)
   ...

def OnStop(self, event):
   ...
   self.taskserver.processStop(self.update)
   ...

def update(self, output):
    """
    Get and print the results from one completed task.
    """
    self.output_tc.AppendText('%s [%d] calculate(%d) = %.2f\n'...
    ...
    # Give the user an opportunity to interact
    wx.YieldIfNeeded()
```

In the class TaskServerMP:

```
def run(self):
   ...
   self.processTasks(self.update)
   ...

def processTasks(self, resfunc=None):
   ...

def processStop(self, resfunc=None): 
   ...

def update(self, output):
    """
    Get and print the results from one completed task.
    """
    sys.stdout.write('%s [%d] calculate(%d) = %.2f' % ....
```

So I thought that is a dependency injection practice but nothing more. I then removed it from the code and the strangest thing happened -- the program doesn't work anymore! I have the GUI displayed and I was able to start the processing. However, the GUI just hanged and then later Windows reported that the program is not responding. I have end up kill all the pythonw.exe processes manually from the Windows Task Manager.

Then I start to think if there is anything to do with the signature of the functions **processTasks** and **processStop** in the class **TaskServerMP**. But I really have no idea how I can associate the parameter **self.update** to the optional argument **resfunc**.

I don't think there is anything wrong in Roger's code. But it bothers me if I cannot twisted around the source to test out my understanding of the code.

I use Python 2.7 in Windows 7.

Comment: PS, Python doesn't really have such a thing as "private variable". The closest thing is has are variables starting with underscores. `self.update` is as public as can be. If you have a `MyFrame` instance, you can even write `myframe.update = foo` to replace it with something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyFrame.update` is a method. You can see its definition on line 365.

So `self.update` is a bound method, meaning it can be called as if it were a regular function.

You can see that `processTasks` takes a `resfunc` parameter; then, at least 165, if it got a function or method as that `resfunc` parameter, it calls it.

The idea here is that `processTasks` leaves it up to the caller to decide how to print out progress updates as each task completes. One class might do it by writing them to stdout. A different class might instead update a GUI progress bar.

This is a pretty typical way to pass callbacks around in Python code.

---

So, why does the program hang if you take out the `self.update`? Well, look what's inside it, at line 372:

```
    # Give the user an opportunity to interact
    wx.YieldIfNeeded()
```

In wx, as in most GUI frameworks, the main thread is running an "event loop", something which has to process each event (a mouse move, a keypress, whatever) as it comes in, and then wait for the next one. You write your code as a bunch of event handlers—when someone clicks this button, run that function; etc. Your event handlers have to return quickly. Otherwise, the event loop doesn't get to pick up and dispatch the next event, so your GUI isn't responding. In wx, the `Yield` family of functions make life easier. As long as you Yield often enough, you don't have to return quickly. But you still have to do one or the other—either return early, or Yield—or the GUI will hang.

---

Here's a very simple example showing how to use bound methods:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)
    def give_me_a_printer_function(self):
        return self.print_name

spam = Foo('Spam')
my_function1 = spam.print_name
my_function2 = spam.give_me_a_printer_function()
my_function1()
my_function2()
```

This will print `Spam` twice.

Functions and methods are *first class values* in Python—you can pass them around just like you can pass around numbers, strings, lists, and class instances. You can even print them out (although you'll get something ugly like `<bound method Foo.print_name of <__main__.Foo object at 0x104629190>>`).

Comment: Thanks. However, shouldn't it be referred to as self.update(...)? The function definition of the **Update** function includes a required parameter.

Comment: @TorukMakto: No, `self.update` is a bound method, a thing that can be passed around and called later. `self.update(…)` would call the function right now, and pass the result.

Comment: @TorukMakto: Does my example make sense? If not, tell me what part you don't get, and maybe I can clarify it better.

Comment: Thanks abarnert. The explanation is clear. But how to associate the method being passed with the **resfunc** parameter? isn't it should become **processTasks(resfunc=self.update)**?

Comment: @TorukMakto: Why? In Python, you _can_ specify arguments by name, but you don't have to (except for keyword-only arguments, of course). If I write `def foo(a)`, calling `foo(1)` is exactly the same thing as calling `foo(a=1)`.

Comment: Thanks. Everything got sorted out.

Comment: Were you confused by the `self` parameter? Remember that in Python, every instance method in a class has to take an explicit `self` as the first parameter, but the callers don't have to pass it. (This is different from Java-style object-oriented languages, if that's what you're used to.)